# How mathematical is artificial intelligence as a focus?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Compared to mechanical engineering, computer engineering, or software engineering how do the mathematics compare? What should be mathematics that I should start focusing on learning now or should expect to learn if I want to become a researcher in the field or an industry expert? I am currently a senior in high school who is considering AI. Math doesn't scare me.

Comment: Modern AI and machine learning are strongly informed by Bayesian probability theory, and to work in that domain effectively you will also need a strong mastery of calculus and linear algebra.  From there, it depends on your focus and inclination, but those are the core mathematical tools.

Answer (score 1):

In AI one of the most important goals is to make computer act(and think!) like humans. For this purpose computers must learn models from observations(data) and act based on that model. This learning and prediction needs deep understanding of probability theory, statistics and stochastic processes as fundamental tools.

Today, probability and statistics are considered general mathematics like calculus and all undergraduate students are familiar with them, but you need to master them if your research field is in AI.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the following:

1. Probability - Bayesian Theory
2. Statistics - Data Interpretation, Graph Plotting, Graph Error Handling
3. Stochastic Theory
4. Entropy Theory (for finding degree of errant data)
5. Matrices and their computational formulae, use stochastic matrices

Since AI uses a lot of trees and graphs, a look into state space search and heuristic calculation would be quite useful..